# Size/Content Column in Chrome Network Tool showing non consistent results for Amplience CDN

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, performance-testing, cdn, web-performance

Attached are three screenshots from Google Chrome Network Tools for the same website.

They are filtered to show images from the Amplience CDN

The results shown in the Size/Content column vary and I am trying to understand why.

Each screenshot is taken from the point of view of a returning user. Therefore the images should come from Cache.

Screenshot 1 - Shows a big difference between Size on Disk and Transfer Size. 
Screenshot 2 - Shows that one of the images is now NOT cached
Screenshot 3 - the term (from Cache) is now displayed.

My questions are:

1. In screenshot 1, why does it not say (from cache)? What is happening in the small amounts of Transfer Size that is not happening in screenshot 3?
2. Why is it that one image is suddenly not cached?

   [image: Screenshot 1 - big difference between Size on Disk and Transfer Size]
   [image: Screenshot 2 - one of the images is now NOT cached]
   [image: Screenshot 3 - the term (from Cache) is now displayed]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My responses:

> 1. In screenshot 1, why does it not say (from cache)? What is happening in the small amounts of Transfer Size that is not happening
>      in screenshot 3?

If you had the "Status" displayed, you'd probably see a "304 Not Modified". In this case, the cache was used **AND** the network was used. A request was sent to the server and the response only contains headers that are 257 bytes long.

> 2. Why is it that one image is suddenly not cached?

There can be many reasons so it's hard to answer without more information.

- It could be that you asked for a "hard refresh" (Ctrl + Shift + R).
- It could be that the response contained a "Age" header that was bigger than the "Cache-Control: max-age=xxx", or a "Date" header that was too far in the past.
- I can also think of a case when the browser sends a request with a "If-modified-Since" header or a "Etag" header, and your servers (in your case the CDN servers) do not all respond with the same information.
- Browsers sometime remove things from the cache, usually when they need to make space for some other files.

Comment: I have rerun the test. Not been able to re-produce Screenshot 2 but I have reproduced Screenshots 1 and 3. Your suggestion regarding Status 304 is correct. In Summary, Status 200 leads to (from Cache), Status 304 to small amount of bytes. What factors determine whether a Status 304 or 200 is given? @Gael Metals

Comment: @Spencer There is a 304 response when the server knows that the client already has the same file in cache. For this to happen, the client's request has to send a 'ETag' or a 'Last-Modified' header, that was previously provided by the server. So you get a 304 when the file is in cache but the max-age is expired (or the user pressed the refresh button), + the previous response was containing one of these headers.

Comment: thanks @gael metais. I am getting 304s even when the max-age has not been expired.

Comment: @Spencer Did you refresh the page?